# Declare a big int as a list parameter with out using a temp table

Tags: sql-server, parameters, powerbi

I have the following query which I will later turn into a stored procedure. I have a `bigint` column in which I use to filter out data as follows

```
select *
from table 1
where id <> 35698
and id <> 14589
and id <> 45698
and id <> 47859
```

I want to declare the id column as a parameter, so this is what I tried

```
declare @ID varchar
set @ID='(35698,14589,45698,47859)'
select *
from table 1
where id not in @ID
```

but now it tells me that:

> error converting from varchar to bigiInt"

which I understand because the id column is a int.

Is there any way I can achieve this with out using a temp table, because I am going to get the values for the `@ID` parameter from Power BI and Power BI passes the `@ID` parameters as such

```
"35698","14589","45698","47859"
```

So my question is how would I pass those parameters into my `where` clause?

Comment: This is a very common misunderstanding. The engine is NOT going to treat your variable as some sort of macro and expand the content into your query before compiling. Suggest you read Erland's discussion on [arrays and lists](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) along with the related sections on using table-valued parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your version of SQL Server, this is a straightforward task using `STRING_SPLIT`.

The following example requires **SQL Server 2016** or greater.

```
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(255)='35698,14589,45698,47859';

SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT CAST ( [value] AS BIGINT ) FROM STRING_SPLIT ( @id, ',' )
);
```

Running the following query against the **@id** list:

```
SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT ( @id, ',' );
```

Returns

```
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
| 35698 |
| 14589 |
| 45698 |
| 47859 |
+-------+
```

Comment: Hi i tried this but it says Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '
  14589' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute this as a dynamic query:

```
declare @list varchar(1000)
  set @list ='12321312,123123,432523,12324213'
  declare @sql nvarchar(Max)
  
  Set @sql='SELECT * FROM TABLE 1 WHERE Id NOT IN ('+@list+')'
  EXECUTE(@sql)
```